# How to convert data of a file to human readable format

Tags: android-studio, file, encoding

I have been developing an android app. I deleted by mistake the partition which had the code on it while dual booting my laptop with fedora. I recovered the files back using a software name remo recovery but the contents of the file are now in some other translation. I tried using chardetect, file -i command on linux but none of them showed any thing useful. Please help me to figure out how to convert the data of this file to a human readable format.
`瓋镙됴ᦃ璊柦侨㍩彪る䥤☽༢㓴띊幗秠숺⫾⥙⮍漸샦泽Ｏꤹ턮ᮧ㙢膸햿늤蹚㗳쬮쐍鳛曷⩫场軸秪罉울컮뵵狳➵ଦ电鰤튆흝햸ß�棭䫊ފ揶髦⮳易ꌨூ鉽乸੼ﯤﱸ氓ㇸ蛊⵨䷠璶襖⫰꠶⮏䊱꟞둣쌬蟵⊚훨㶺﷕⭷幠�働ꊖਧ㱫﵈鑁ᅥӫ襞䦛૧︑ꈋ⵻鱄긻⨷䪊鿶쑸쯭鴮㳬諕鵒ꞧ`
This is just a part of the whole code.
This shows UTF16LE in the notepad. Please Help.

Comment: Given example seems to be part of a binary file…

Comment: I tried depickling it up but it didn't work. Any other way to get around it?